# DreamFactory problems sending email

Tags: php, json, rest

Okay so I setup my own locally running copy of DreamFactory ... all this works on the hosted version ... but my problem when i try to send a test email using say this:

```
{
"to": [
    {
      "name": "Demo",
      "email": "demo@acme.com"
    }
  ],
  "subject": "Testing SMTP Email Service",
  "body_text": "I am sending a Test email from my DSP."
}
```

I get this response:

```
{
  "error": [
    {
      "context": null,
      "message": "Failed to send to the following addresses:Array\n(\n    [0] =&gt;   demo@acme.com\n)\n",
      "code": 500
    }
  ]
}
```

Seems to me it's trying to use all of that for the email address instead of the address itself and I can not figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Please try upgrading to the newest version of the DSP (v. 1.7.8)

I was able to use this json on my localhost and all was okay:

```
{
  "to": [{
      "name": "Demo",
      "email": "demo@acme.com"
  }],
  "subject": "Testing SMTP Email Service",
  "body_text": "I am sending a Test email from my DSP."
}
```

If it gives another issue after you upgrade, please let me know.

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: How did you setup your E-mail service initially?